# Двоеточие перед перечислением (2)

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, двоеточие

"Озаренный свечой ты сиял(,) светились глаза твои цвета весеннего неба, лучились, ушки пламенели, взлохмаченный пух белых волосиков нимбом окружал твою голову"

Почему после "сиял" стоит запятая, а не двоеточие? 
Нет обобщающего слова, но во второй части идет разъяснение первой, или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Оригинал выглядит так:

***Озаренный свечой, ты сиял, светился, глаза твои, цвета весеннего неба, лучились, ушки пламенели, взлохмаченный пух белых волосиков нимбом окружал твою голову, и мне на миг показалось, что ты прозрачен, что не только спереди, но и сзади ты освещен свечой.*** (Юрий Казаков. "Двое в декабре")

Это предложение можно, конечно, оформить пунктуационно по-другому, только стоит ли это делать?

Но, отвечая на ваш вопрос, скажу, что можно первую часть предложения с РВС оформить как предложение с бессоюзной связью:

***Озаренный свечой, ты сиял, светился: глаза твои, цвета весеннего неба, лучились, ушки пламенели, взлохмаченный пух белых волосиков нимбом окружал твою голову...*** — Три предложения после двоеточия поясняют первое предложение, раскрывая его содержание.

Answer (score 1):

В авторском варианте **очень много запятых**, из-за чего возникают некоторые трудности про прочтении текста.

Известных авторов обычно не правят, но всё-таки представим, что текст просили проверить и  отредактировать.

Чтобы поставить **двоеточие,**  нужно, чтобы все предложения имели **пояснительное значение** по отношению к первому, а это не совсем так.

Поэтому я бы, например, поставила **точку:**

*Озаренный свечой, ты сиял, светился. Глаза твои, цвета весеннего неба, лучились, ушки пламенели, взлохмаченный пух белых волосиков нимбом окружал твою голову, и мне на миг показалось, что ты прозрачен, что не только спереди, но и сзади ты освещен свечой.*

**Почему мне ещё не  нравится двоеточие**

Это предложение имеет сложное строение: 7 простых предложений. По смыслу их можно разделить на три блока: (1) ты светился (начало темы); (2) как это выглядело; (3) что мне показалось. Бессоюзная связь между 1 и 2 ослабит связь между 2 и 3, **а там связь тесная,** и пауза там короткая.

Поэтому из начала темы делаем **отдельное предложение**, а далее сочинительная связь (союз И) между блоками 2 и 3.